# Looking for suggestions on scheduling iCloud Photo Library uploads

Tags: icloud, photos

I have a 57GB photo library that I would like to keep in iCloud Photo library, the only problem is that my ISP absolutely murders my download speed whenever I'm uploading *anything*.

Is there a way that I can schedule Photos to upload my library *only* during off-peak hours (rather than waking up at 2am, un-pausing the upload and then pausing it again at 7am manually).

I was thinking maybe a third party application like *Little Snitch* might work (I've never tried it) or something along those lines, maybe even some kind of Apple Script.

I'm a bit over my head with this so I need some help

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complex but here's a way.

[How to Throttle iCloud Photo Library Uploads](https://tidbits.com/article/15679)